# Pushing value of Var into an Array jquery

Tags: jquery, angular, ionic2

I have an array that can contain a number of values (car) depending on what a user has entered. I want to add variable to the array.

```
<div class="demo">
    <span id="cartabs1"></span>
</div>
<ion-input type="text" placeholder="Add new tag" value=""></ion-input> 
<button  (click)="addtag">Add</button>
```

file.ts

```
cars = ["friends","oil","Ford","Peugeot","Ferrari"]; 
 ngAfterViewInit() {
    jQuery('#cartabs1').tabSelect({
       tabElements: cars,
       selectedTabs: [ ]
  });
  }
  addtag() {
        cars.push(jQuery("#cartabs1").val());
         console.log(cars);
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the `this` keyword:

```
 addtag() {
        this.cars.push(jQuery("#cartabs1").val());
        console.log(this.cars);
  });
```

Please notice that you're trying to push the value of the span and not the value entered in the ion-input... is that intentionally?

Comment: Could you put your code in a plunker? Please notice that you're trying to push the value of the `span` and not the value entered in the `ion-input`... is that intentionally?